# Is there a way to allow for strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders() Function into an IF statement?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to only trigger one trade per day. However, when my Long Condition is true, the alert always activates, regardless of having the strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders() Function in the script.
I was wondering if there is a way to incorporate this function into the IF statement.

The full code can be seen below:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Test" , shorttitle="Test - V2", overlay=true, initial_capital =100000, default_qty_value = 8000, pyramiding =0, default_qty_type = strategy.fixed, currency=currency.USD)

//Settings
pc_prefix        = input(title="Symbol Prefix", defval="", type=input.string, group="Settings")

//Generate Alert String
symbol = pc_prefix + syminfo.ticker
pc_entry_alert(direction, sl, tp) =>
    direction + "," + symbol + "," + "sl=" +tostring(sl) + ",tp=" + tostring(tp) 

// Get user input
pipStop          = input(title="Pip Stop Amount", defval = 10.0, type=input.float, step=1, group ="PIP Values")  
pipTP2           = input(title="Pip Take Profit 2", defval = 20.0, type=input.float, step=1, group="PIP Values")  


//Strategy maximum number of intraday trades
strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(2)


//Getting Previous Session High/Low 

rp_function(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1:0])

dHigh = rp_function(syminfo.ticker, "D", high[1]) 
dLow = rp_function(syminfo.ticker, "D", low[1])

plot(dHigh, color=color.blue)
plot(dLow, color=color.orange)


//Defining the Trade
goLongCondition1 = close> dHigh 


// Entry Condition for setup
validLong = strategy.position_size == 0 and goLongCondition1 



// Calculate our stop distance & size for the current bar
longStopPrice = close - pipStop
longStopDistance = close - longStopPrice
longTargetPrice2 = close + pipTP2
longEntryPrice = validLong? close:na


// Save trade stop & target & position size if a valid setup is detected
var tradeLongStopPrice = 0.0
var tradeLongTargetPrice2 = 0.0
var tradeLongEntryPrice = 0.0



// Detect valid long setups & trigger alert
if validLong
    tradeLongStopPrice := longStopPrice
    tradeLongTargetPrice2 := longTargetPrice2
    tradeLongEntryPrice := longEntryPrice


//Alerts  
if validLong 
    alert_string = pc_entry_alert("buy",tradeLongStopPrice, tradeLongTargetPrice2)
    alert(alert_string, alert.freq_all)
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long)



// Exit trades whenever our stop or target is hit
strategy.exit(id="LTP1", from_entry="Long", limit=tradeLongTargetPrice2, stop=tradeLongStopPrice, when=strategy.position_size > 0, qty_percent = 100)


//Strategy maximum number of intraday trades
strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(2)
```

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: @BarisYakut The full code can be seen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up your alert, select "Order fills only".

[image]

Otherwise, every time `validLong` becomes `true`, you will get an alert because you are using `alert()` function in that if block.

## **Edit:**

You can use the `alert_message` property of `strategy.entry()` and `strategy.exit()` calls. This way you will only get alert messages when those `strategy` calls are executed.

Change this:

```
//Alerts  
if validLong 
    alert_string = pc_entry_alert("buy",tradeLongStopPrice, tradeLongTargetPrice2)
    alert(alert_string, alert.freq_all)
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long)
```

to this:

```
alert_string = pc_entry_alert("buy",tradeLongStopPrice, tradeLongTargetPrice2)
strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long, when=validLong, alert_message=alert_string)
```

If you want to have a different message on `strategy.exit()` call, you can define a new string and use `strategy.exit()`'s `alert_message` property too.

Comment: hey thank you. 
The only downside with that approach is that it would generate an alert on the close of the trade as well. Do you know if there could be a way around that? 
I'm trying to automate the strategy, and any alert would be routed through an API connector.

Comment: So, you only want to have an alert when your are going long, correct? Would that be useful if we generate a specific alert message when you are going long and another one for the exit?

Comment: Yes i'd only want to have an alert when going long. 
The way it's currently set up, is that with every alert (Long Entry  or Exit); the Take Profit and Stop loss levels are set in that instant. So currently having the alert trigger on the exit of the trade would not be beneficial. 
But yes; if a different alert message can be triggered on the exit of the strategy, it can help.

Comment: Hello @dmikes, could you please see my edit and tell me if it helps?

Comment: Hey thank you. Ill test it from now. The strategy will take a while to give those signals. So I'll update you when i get confirmation.

Comment: No problem. I slighty modified your code and tested it on a 5 sec chart. It should work. Just let me know if it does not work as expected and if it works, you can accept my answer.

Comment: Hey i took your advice and slightly modified it as well and put it on a 1m chart. It works great. Thank you so much man !! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I was able to help and thanks for letting me know. What was your modification? I can add it to my answer and if someone else has the same problem they would have the full solution.

Comment: I changed the Long Entry condition to trigger when the current close is greater than the previous closing price. So it would generate signals more frequently.

Comment: Ah okay, so it’s just your strategy. Nothing related to my answer. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I took your advice on adjusting the alert_message and setting alerts to only trigger on Order Fills. So your advice worked perfectly with what i was trying to accomplish.